# Get specific parameters from all functions in javascript file

Tags: javascript, regex, shell

Sample input file

```
function getRepoReviewers(gitHost, repoURL) {
     return {
          method: 'GET', headers: "",
          url: `v1/api/code/${gitHost}/reviewers/${repoURL}`
     }
}

function getRepoBranches(gitHost, repoURL) {
     return {
          method: 'GET', headers: "",
          url: `v1/api/code/${gitHost}/branches/${repoURL}`
     }
}
```

Expected output to get

```
GET, v1/api/code/${gitHost}/reviewers/${repoURL}
GET, v1/api/code/${gitHost}/branches/${repoURL}
```

I tried with help of below shell script to read line by line using below regex but not able to get the desired result.

```
for entry in "$1"/*
do
  var=$(tr '´' "'" < $entry);
  printf "%s" "$var" > file.txt;
  list1=$(grep -o "[^']*v1[^']*" file.txt);
  list2=$(grep -o "[^']*v2[^']*" file.txt);
  echo "$list1" >> api_endpoints_bat_api.csv
  echo >> api_endpoints_bat_api.csv
  echo "$list2" >> api_endpoints_bat_api.csv
  echo >> api_endpoints_bat_api.csv
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one-liner using pipes:

```
cat test.js |\
 egrep 'method:|url:' |\
 perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/} s/\s+url:/ url:/g' |\
 grep '.' |\
 tr '`' "'" |\
 perl -pe "s/.*method: '([^']*)'.*url: '([^']*).*/\1,\2/"
```

Output with your file:

```
GET,v1/api/code/${gitHost}/reviewers/${repoURL}
GET,v1/api/code/${gitHost}/branches/${repoURL}
```

Explanation:

- `egrep`: use only lines of interest
- 1st `perl`: join the url line with previous line, the `BEGIN{undef $/}` tells perl to be in multi-line mode
- `grep`: use only non-empty lines
- `tr`: change back quote to `'`
- 2nd `perl`: capture and use only method and url

BTW, if you want to feed this to a `.csv` file you should omit the space after the comma.

Comment: You're welcome Tushar. Does this answer your question? If so would you care to accept it (see gray checkmark)?

Comment: My bad, just given, this works for my use case. Thanks